# moderncv: how to change the separator between address and city

Tags: header-footer, moderncv

I'd like to know how to change the separator between address and city in `moderncv` theme`\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}` you can see in the figure further down. I know the bullets can be modified by `\footersymbol` but this does not affect the hyphens above. And so far I did not find a solution. I'd like to have the hyphens replaced by the bullets. Would anyone help, please.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{test}

\end{document}
```

**Edit 1:**

I modified the suggestion by Torbjørn T. which gives me the following result:

[image]

I replaced `[~\textbullet~]` by `[\footersymbol]` adapting the different spacing between the bullets in the first and the following lines. Simultaneously I was able to modify the bullets color globaly by `\renewcommand*{\footersymbol}{{~~~{\rmfamily\textcolor{color1}{\textbullet}}~~~}}`. As far it is exactly what I want, even a bit more ;). Thanks for your help :)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}

\renewcommand*{\footersymbol}{{~~~{\rmfamily\textcolor{color1}{\textbullet}}~~~}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvfooter}{%
  \setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox[b]{\footerwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofooter[\footersymbol]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofooter[\footersymbol]{\@addresscountry}}%
          \flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}%
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \addtofooter{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofooter{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
        \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
          \addtofooter{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofooter{\@extrainfo}}%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footerboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfooter}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
        }}}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dashes seem to be 'hardcoded' in the `\makecvfooter` macro. Below I copied the definition of that macro from `moderncvstylecasual.sty` and changed `~--~` to `~\textbullet~` in two places.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvfooter}{%
  \setlength{\footerwidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyfoot[c]{%
      \parbox[b]{\footerwidth}{%
        \centering%
        \color{color2}\addressfont%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}% forces a white line to ensure space between main text and footer (as footer height can't be known in advance)
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofooter[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~\textbullet~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtofooter[~\textbullet~]{\@addresscountry}}%
          \flushfooter\@firstfooterelementtrue\\}%
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \addtofooter{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtofooter{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtofooter{\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}}%
        \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
          \addtofooter{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtofooter{\@extrainfo}}%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\footerboxwidth=0pt}}{}{\flushfooter}% the lengthtest is required to avoid flushing an empty footer, which could cause a blank line due to the \\ after the address, if no other personal info is used
        }}}%
  \pagestyle{plain}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just posted the same answer

Comment: @touhami I see. What do you expect me to do about that?

Comment: Nothing. It just anthor way to say sorry i didn't see your answer first

Comment: @touhami Oh, no need to apologize. You could consider deleting your own answer though. (Up to you of course, but as you say  your answer was basically the same as mine.)

Comment: i will delete the answer

Comment: I appreciate your both answer, thnaks a lot!